# How to empty the dropzone modal after submitted in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I was wondering how can I empty the files inside on dropzone after it is already saved in the server and the database? My problem is when I submitted it maintain the files on the dropzone and even on the modal closed. I wish I can give a code about emptying the dropzone but I don't have any idea so instead I will leave the code of dropzone and onsubmit.

The code for onsbumit

```
onSubmit() {
        debugger
        form.Status=0;
        form.isActive=true;
        return(form.Key > 0 ? this.creater : this.creater).call(this, form);
        return false;
}
```

the code for ondrop

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles, e) {
        debugger
        console.log('Received files: ', acceptedFiles);
        this.setState({files: acceptedFiles});      
        const req = request.post('http://localhost:8933/api/upload/post');
        acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
            req.attach(thisUuid , file);
        });
         req.end(callback);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone has a method `removeAllFiles` that deletes all files that are currently in dropzone instance (the usage is something like `Dropzone.removeAllFiles()`).

You'd want to call in the callback that is invoked when you have finished uploading your files to the server.

You might also be interested [this](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Remove-all-files-with-one-button) tutorial on how to delete files.