# How to empty the dropzone after submit reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-dropzone

I was wondering how can I empty the files inside on dropzone after it is already saved in the server and the database. My problem is when I submitted it maintain the files on the dropzone and even on the modal closed, I wish I can give a code about emptying the dropzone but I don't have any idea so instead I will leave the code of dropzone and onsubmit below.

The code for onsubmit

```
onSubmit() {
        debugger
        form.Status=0;
        form.isActive=true;
        return(form.Key > 0 ? this.creater : this.creater).call(this, form);
        return false;
}
```

the code for ondrop

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles, e) {
        debugger
        console.log('Received files: ', acceptedFiles);
        this.setState({files: acceptedFiles});      
        const req = request.post('http://localhost:8933/api/upload/post');
        acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
            req.attach(thisUuid , file);
        });
         req.end(callback);
    }
```

my problem was is not refreshing the renderImage files when i submit it

```
renderImg(file, index) {
    debugger
        let ext = file.name.split(".").slice(-1)[0];
        if(ext === "PNG" ||ext === "png" || ext === "jpg") {    
            return (<div> <i className="fa fa-file-image-o" ></i>{file.name}</div>)
        }
        if(ext === "doc" || ext === "docx") {
            return (<div> <i className="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>{file.name}</div>)
        }
        if(ext === "pdf" || ext === "pdf") {
            return (<div> <i className="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> {file.name}</div>)
        }
        if(ext === "xlsx" || ext === "xls") {
            return (<div> <i className="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> {file.name}</div>)
        }       

        return (
            <div key={index} className="pms-file-preview drop-box">
                <div className="pms-file-footer">
                    <div className="pms-file-caption drop-caption" title={file.name}>
                        {file.name}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
        return false;
    }
```

and lastly the dropzone

```
<Dropzone  
                        accept = ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.odt,.jpg,.png,.xls,.xlsx"
                        onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                        className="pms-upload">
                        {this.state.files.length > 0 ? 
                            <div>{this.state.files.map(this.renderImg)}</div> : 
                            <div className="pms-upload-title">
                                Click or drag & drop files here
                             </div>
                        }
                    </Dropzone>
```

Comment: `this.setState({files: null})` when you need to empty the files

Comment: @Fawaz Where should I put it? onsubmit? please help me im so confuse..

Comment: Yes put it inside onSubmit

Comment: @Fawaz thank you it worked but instead of null i changed it to `files:[]`

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to empty the dropzone modal after submitted in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140620/how-to-empty-the-dropzone-modal-after-submitted-in-reactjs)

Comment: This is a copy+paste duplicate of your prior question, please do not do this. I would normally downvote, but I have downvoted you elsewhere, and we try not to serially-downvote people.

Answer (score 0):

to empty the droppe items you should make the files empty again by using set state

```
  onSubmit() {
            debugger
            form.Status=0;
            form.isActive=true;
            this.setState({files: []})
            return(form.Key > 0 ? this.creater : this.creater).call(this, form);
            return false;
    }
```